# Where does kevent() validate its file descriptor?

Tags: system-calls, freebsd, file-descriptor

Let's say we have a simple program like this:

```
int fd;
kq = kqueue();
EV_SET(&kev, fd, EVFILT_VNODE, EV_ADD, 0, 0, NULL);
kevent(kq, &kev, 1, &ke, 1, &timeout)
```

Where does `kevent` check to see if `fd` is a valid file descriptor? It might find out that the file descriptor denoted by `fd` is closed.

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) what are you asking. What would happen if you pass kevent a closed fd?

Comment: @arrowd Thanks for your reply. Yes, what would happen if I pass kevent a closed fd? I think there is such a check in kevent, but I don't find it....

Comment: Well, you can just compile your code and try. I guess, kevent wouldn't return -1 to indicate a error, but simply drop this filter, because this is what it does when fd being watched is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to cover how a syscall happens in freebsd (you may owe the oracle another question), however, sys_kevent() (/usr/src/sys/kern/kern_event.c) is called and it calls kern_kevent() (same file).  In the code below, fget(fd) checks your file descriptor (for exsiting, permissions, etc.  Probably locks it, too) before handing back a file pointer.

```
int
kern_kevent(struct thread *td, int fd, int nchanges, int nevents,
    struct kevent_copyops *k_ops, const struct timespec *timeout)
{
    cap_rights_t rights;
    struct file *fp;
    int error;

    cap_rights_init(&rights);
    if (nchanges > 0)
        cap_rights_set(&rights, CAP_KQUEUE_CHANGE);
    if (nevents > 0)
        cap_rights_set(&rights, CAP_KQUEUE_EVENT);
    error = fget(td, fd, &rights, &fp);
    if (error != 0)
        return (error);

    error = kern_kevent_fp(td, fp, nchanges, nevents, k_ops, timeout);
    fdrop(fp, td);

    return (error);
}
```

Heh... at what point did I become the UTSL nazi?  Sigh.